# Javascript "Permission Denied" Error in IE.x

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, https

I did the mistake of creating my entire web application and not testing it on IE along the way. I only tested it on Firefox and Safari. The web app runs fine on both Safari and Firefox but it gives a Permission Denied error on IE.

I am using Google AuthSub authentication and so for authenticating using Google Account, it first redirects to allow the app access to Google Account. After authentication, IE changes 'http' to 'https'. This does not happen with either Firefox or Safari. They remain with the 'http' protocol.

IE then gives a Permission Denied error. Is the JavaScript conflicting with 'https' in any way?

The app is here -> http://ankitahuja.com/apps/proxycal

and the error-causing page is -> http://ankitahuja.com/apps/proxycal/proxycal.php

Answer (score 1):

When I open up the proxycal.php page in both IE and FF, an error is raised on this line in the Javascript (in `function _run`):

```
calendarService = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarService('proxycal');
```

Here, `calendar` is not a member of `google.gdata`.

I suggest you debug through the call stack to find out what is not being initialized.

Comment: That's weird because it's opening without any errors on FF and Safari for me. calendar is a member of google.gdata,http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/jsdoc/1.7/index.html and I am including http://www.google.com/jsapi at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

I've run into that error before in IE. Most often, it was because I was fetching data from another domain using `XmlHttpRequest`. Check the "allow data from other domains" setting in IE's Internet Options, make sure it's allowed and then see if you get the same error.

Comment: Where did you find the "allow data from other domains" setting in IE? I didn't see it in 8.

Answer (score 0):

In IE you can use `XDomainRequest`, but not for https from http, which is blocked and [This is an expected by-design behavior](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=333380) (though not expected in FF/Chrome)